# How to derive a uniform sum of n-dice with s-sides using a 60-sided die toss

Tags: probability, dice

My daughter gave me a 60-sided die for Christmas, and this month, I introduced her to D&D. It's trivial to represent a single toss uniformly of a d4, d6, d10, d12, & d20 using modular arithmetic, and handling rerolls, the same can be applied for d8 and d100.

But what if I want the sum of 3d4 using only my d60. [I could use lookup tables](https://flyinghorseduck.com/pages/d60-quick-tables), but I'm curious how I would derive it via equation. In other words, if I toss a 49, how could I uniformly derive the sum of 3d4 without a lookup table?

It seems like the approach would be to first get the probabilities of each sum of 3 through 12 in 3d4, then apply those probabilities to 10 groupings of the d60. Knowing that the probabilities won't divide the d60 evenly, rerolls will also need to be handled.

It seems like I need to use a probability generating function, but it's not clear to me how to apply it, such that looking at the result of my d60 toss, I can uniformly derive the sum of an s-sided die with n-tosses.

Comment: Does $3d4$ mean the sum of three rolls of a $4$-sided die?  If so, the sum should run from $3$ to $12$.

Comment: yes, in fact, what is 3d4 ?what is the meaning of your notation ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: A lookup table *is* a function that takes a d60 roll and returns a 3d4 roll.  One could write a complicated algebraic expression to give the result of my table below, but I don't think it would be as easy as using the table.  Compared to the table you link, mine sacrifices accuracy for the ease of having an answer in one roll.

Comment: I agree a lookup table is more convenient, but it's the algebraic expression I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can simulate d4 using d60 you can easily simulate 3d4 by the sum of 3d60s. You can devise a method that will obtain it faster making use of the $15$ possibilities that are left after each roll. One obvious improvement would be to obtain d4 roll from the d60 roll by dividing the number one less than the result by 4 and get the remainder plus one and if the quotient is less than $12$ then we can simulate the next result of a d4 roll by dividing with the remainder by $4$ again. For example, if we roll $40$ we divide $40-1=39$ by $4$ obtaining $9$ and residue $3$ - therefore our first roll is $3+1=4$ and we can use the quotient $9$ to roll the second time - dividing it by $4$ we obtain the remainder of $1$ so our second throw is $2$. So most of the time we need just two rolls except for the case when the remainder will be $12$, $13$ or $14$ two times in a row. The probability of this happening is $(\frac{3}{15})^2=4\%$ giving us an average of $2.04$ rolls. And it can be improved further, for example, if we get twice the quotient $12$ or $13$ we can assign each of the pairs $(12,12)$, $(12,13)$, $(13,12)$ and $(13,13)$ an outcome of the third d4 dice so the only case in which we have to roll the dice for the third time would be when we get the remainder $14$ two times in a row - the probability of this happening is just $(\frac{1}{16})^2=\frac{1}{256} \approx .39\%$.

Comment: Isn't the base-2 entropy of a d60 ≈ 5.90689?

Comment: Yes, the entropy of a d60 is $5.90689$ and the entropy of 3d4 is $2.98427$. So the information bound in this case is useless because we obviously need at least one roll. Thank you for pointing that out, I've removed this part from my answer.

Comment: Okay. I'm with you up until you state that we can get quotients 12, 13, or 14 two times in a row. If the 2nd quotient is dependent on the 1st, won't the only valid range for the 2nd quotients be 0-3? For example, if you roll 60, 60-1=59. Thus 59/4 is 14 remainder 3, so the 1st result is 4. The second roll would then be 14/4, which is 3 remainder 2, so the 2nd result is 3. Would the concern be getting 12-14 as the 1st quotient and 3 for the 2nd quotient?

Comment: If we roll $60$ (or any number greater than $48$) we just obtain one d4 roll from this roll. So in the case of $60$ we just get the value of $4$. But if next time we roll something smaller than $48$ like $40$, then we can extract information about two rolls - $4$ and $2$ as in the answer and we get the sum equal to $10$.

Comment: This works perfectly, and I can generalize this further. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that there are $4^3=64$ results from throwing three four-sided dice.  If it were less than $60$ it would be much easier.  What you can do is throw your d60 twice, which gives $3600$ possibilities.  As $\frac {3600}{64}=56\frac14$ you can assign $56$ results to each result of 3d4.  It will be rather messy.

The way the tables are calculated is to add up possibilities to get the proper probabilities.  The first table assigns two numbers out of $60$ to a roll of $4$, giving a chance of $\frac 2{60}$.  The chance for a roll of $4$ is $\frac 3{64}$ so you sill need to account for $\frac {19}{360}$ and they use the lower possibilities to do that.  The next table gives you a chance of $\frac 1{10}\cdot \frac 7{60}$ to roll a $4$, which is still not enough, so you keep going.

If you are willing to approximate for the sake of simplicity, reduce the number of results for $6,7,8,9$ by $1$ each, giving $60$ results.  The result is
$$\begin{array} {r r r r} \text{d60 roll}&\text{3d4 roll}&\text{d60 probability}&\text{3d4 probability}\\
\hline 1&3&\frac 1{60}&\frac 1{64} \\
2-4&4&\frac 3{60}&\frac 3{64}\\
5-10&5&\frac 6{60}&\frac6{64}\\
11-19&6&\frac 9{60}&\frac{10}{64}\\
20-30&7&\frac{11}{60}&\frac{12}{64}\\
31-41&8&\frac{11}{60}&\frac{12}{64}\\
42-50&9&\frac 9{60}&\frac{10}{64}\\
51-56&10&\frac 6{60}&\frac6{64}\\
57-59&11&\frac 3{60}&\frac 3{64}\\
60&12&\frac 1{60}&\frac 1{64}\end {array}$$

Comment: How did you derive the 3d4 probabilities? This is where I'm struggling where I need to derive it generally. It seems recursive, as the probabilities of a 3d4 are dependent on the results of 2d4 which is further dependent on 1d4 (25% probability each).

Comment: I just used a spreadsheet.  I made one column with four blank lines at the top and then 1-12 in the next rows representing the sums of a number of dice.  In the next column I put 1 in the rows with 1-4 which are the number of ways to get that sum with one die.  In the second column I wrote =sum(left and up 4:left and up 1) representing the fact that the second die can have any number 1-4.  Then I put the same in the third column and it gave the probabilities.  For example, you can get 5 as 1+1+3, 1+2+2, 1+3+1, 2+1+2, 2+2+1, 3+1+1 for six ways out of 64.  Summing the third column is a check.

Comment: That you can do with generating functions.  The function for one die is $x+x^2+x^3+x^4$, so the function for three dice is $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$  You can expand this and find the coefficient of each power of $x$.  My spreadsheet is doing the same thing.